# trouble to send request in postman in laravel api.php post method

Tags: laravel, api, post, routes, postman

I write a simple post method Route in api.php and postman errored

I also add put Accept = Application/json in headers and return a value to a

but postman do not work

this is postman error

[postman image issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSPx5.png)

and this is my api.php

```
Route::post('/p', function (Request $request) {
    $a = $request->a;
    return response(a,200);
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::post('/p', function (Request $request) {
    $a = $request->a;
    return response($a, 200);
});
```

You missed the '$' in `response($a, 200)`